# How to get a vector field that maps the slopes of an equation

Tags: vector, field, derivative

Hey so I'm reading this article by Chris Hecker where he has an image of a Parabola surrounded by the a vector field of it's derivative:

[image: vec image]

However he never mentions how exactly he got the vector field equation, and never even states it. He does say he overlayed the vector field of the slopes in Figure 1, by drawing the solution to the slope equation, dy/dx = 2x, as a short vector at each coordinate on the grid.

**How do you create a vector field of the slopes of an equation** in the vector field syntax of
*V = xi + yj*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Figure title** would be clearer if it read:

- The curve `y = x^2`, and the vector field `dy/dx = 2x` for the general case `y = x^2 + C`

---

There are **three** equations at work in the graph above:

1. `y = x^2` - The equation for the parabola drawn - **This is the one long solid curve**
2. `y = x^2 + C` -The equation for all parabolas that fit on the vector field - `C` is a constant. **This is the equation for all parabolas that fit on that vector field**
3. `dy/dx = 2x` The equation for the slope field.  - **This is the slope or [*derivative*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of the both the curve drawn and all the possible curves that can be drawn with `y = x^2 + C` for all constant `C`s**.

Note that `C` is a constant, since the derivative of `y = x^2 + C` with any `C` is `2x`. So the vector field shows how to draw all the different parabolas with different `C`s.

---

So there are two ways to calculate the vector field:

1. Iterate over your desired range of x and y and calculate the slope, `dy/dx`- `2x` independent of `y` in this case - at each point. This is how the author did it.
2. Draw a bunch of parabolas by slowly varying `C` in `y = x^2 + C` over a desired range of - let's say - `x` calculating `y`.

---

Comment: Yes, that's how I can draw it, but what's the equation that represents that field? How do I find it mathematically?

Comment: @Griffin - That is what it is mathematically. It is `dy/dx = 2x`. The integral of that is not `v=xi+yj` - The general form is `y= x^2 + C` where C is a constant.

Comment: Ok, and *dy/dx = 2x* translates to *slope = 2x* which translates to ***V= i + 2xj*** or **(Vx= 1, Vy=2x)**

Comment: he also made each vector a unit vector, which can be graphed in a vector field grapher by the equation ***( i + 2xj) / sqrt(1+(2x)^2)***

Comment: @griffin - ah, I see, pythagoras theorem - if I'have time I might try this in JS and Raphael

Comment: or you could use this wonderful vector field grapher to get a quick look: http://kevinmehall.net/p/equationexplorer/vectorfield

Answer (score 1):

For a differential equation dy/dx = f(x,y) (e.g., dy/dx = 2x in this case, with f(x,y) = 2x), the vector field (**F**) will be **F** = **i** + f(x,y)**j** (so in your case, **F** = **i** + 2x **j** )