# how to draw a slope field in matlab

Tags: matlab, math, differential-equations

I was looking for a way to draw slope fields in Matlab.

Here is what I am looking for:

I have an equation

```
dy/dx = f(x,y)
```

or

```
dx/dt = f(x,y)
dy/dt = g(x,y)
```

and I want to draw it in a nice way

Because the only [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761685/how-to-get-a-vector-field-that-maps-the-slopes-of-an-equation) about it here was not answering my question, it took me some time to find how to do this.

Also because this is not something I am doing all the time in matlab (most probably till the next time I will need it, I will forget it) I am creating a memo for me how to do this.

If you will find it useful, feel free to upvote

Answer (score 10, accepted):

so here is the equation:

```
dx/dt = x^2-3xy+y
dy/dt = -5x+sin(yx)
```

That is the code, which will help to do the job:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-2:0.2:2);
dx = x.^2-3*x.*y+y;
dy = -5*x+sin(x.*y);
r = ( dx.^2 + dy.^2 ).^0.5;
px = dx./r;
py = dy./r;
quiver(x,y,px,py);
```

It is also possible to use the package dfield. You can read it [here](http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am33/files/tutorial.pdf). But I have not tested it for myself

Answer (score 1):

Another handy solution would go like:

`[x,y] = meshgrid('start':'step':'end');`

`dy = 'f(x,y)';`

`norm = sqrt(dy.^2+1^2);`

`quiver(x, y, ones(size(x))./norm, dy./norm, 'magnification' )`

---

For example if dy was to be dy = x+y

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-2:0.2:2);

dy = x+y;

norm = sqrt(dy.^2+1^2);

quiver(x, y, ones(size(x))./norm, dy./norm, 0.5 )
```