# Quiver - velocity plot Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, velocity, ode

I am using Matlab quiver to plot these differential equations:

- dx = x.*(1-x-y);
- dy = 2*y.*(1-0.5*y-3/2*x);

I am using this code:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:0.2:2,0:0.2:2);
dx = x.*(1-x-y);
dy = 2*y.*(1-0.5*y-3/2*x);
figure
quiver(x,y,dx,dy)
```

I get this [fig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdj4j.jpg). I don't understand why am I getting tiny arrows even though x an y are sparse!!!
I was expecting something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmyiG.jpg)

My question: Is there a way (if it is possible without using an external package) that makes the arrows larger and colored?

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: If some of your vectors are shorter than others, they will end up small. You can normalize `dx,dy` if you're only interested in magnitudes.

Comment: Yes, that sounds good. I am using this [normalization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747718/how-to-draw-a-slope-field-in-matlab/34256614) r = ( dx.^2 + dy.^2 ).^0.5; dx=dx./r;dy=dy./r; What do you think? it does give good result, but I still don't understand what type of normalization is this?

Comment: It's a normalization where your vector field is normalized to have unit magnitude:) It means that you're not interested in the strength of the flow, only its direction. In case of a PDE this might or might not be what you're after. It also tells you something how strong the flow is in different parts of phase space: if you start from a given point, your trajectory will evolve faster (as a function of time) where the vector field is larger. But if you're interested in how it all looks like, a normalization might be enough.However,at stationary points you'll divide by 0,which is again a problem.

Comment: But the second figure you linked to seems to do just this: normalize the phase flow vector field. It could be cheating a bit: those saddle points definitely correspond to `dx==0 & dy==0`.  Anyway, if your vector field plotting mesh does not coincide with stationary points/lines, you're safe with the normalization approach.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thanks. Can we use the unnormalized dx and dy to assign colors to the flow  in Matlab?. for eg. weak flow will be colored as shades of blue, strong flow shades of red....

Comment: [quiverc](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3225-quiverc) from the file exchange might be useful. That uses the magnitude of the vector field for colors, but you can look inside and try to modify it to use another vector field (the unnormalized one) for color info. I don't think native matlab can do that.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at this package :).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Andras Deak, we came up with this solution:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:0.2:2,0:0.2:2);
dx = x.*(1-x-y);
dy = 2*y.*(1-0.5*y-3/2*x);
% Normalization matrix
r = ( dx.^2 + dy.^2 ).^0.5;
figure
quiver(x,y,dx./r,dy./r)
```